# Write the address of the sender as variable when sending an email in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

This one works,

```
$send = Mail::send('emails.register', $data, function ($message) {
   $message->from('register@mydomain.com', $name = "NAME OF ME")
           ->to('xxxx@yyyy.com')
           ->subject("Activate Your Account");
   });
```

But this one not;

```
 $email = "xxxx@yyyy.com";
 $send = Mail::send('emails.register', $data, function ($message) {
       $message->from('register@mydomain.com', $name = "NAME OF ME")
               ->to($email)
               ->subject("Activate Your Account");
       });
```

What should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: What does the log file in storage/logs/ say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$email` doesn't exist in the scope of your anonymous function.  Import it with `use`:

```
 $send = Mail::send('emails.register', $data, function ($message) use ($email) {
       $message->from('register@mydomain.com', $name = "NAME OF ME")
               ->to($email)
               ->subject("Activate Your Account");
       });
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Thank you!